# Get CPU ticks and measured time

Tags: c++, time, cpu, clock, c++-chrono

So I want to measure time of some functions in C++ and I have tried many ways of doing so. This is my final code:

```
auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
clStart = clock();

for (int o=0; o<100;o++)
{
    sin(o);
   // Sleep(1);
}

auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
clEnd = clock();

auto difTime = end-start;
diff = chrono::duration <double,milli> (difTime).count(); //gives me 0
diffTicks = clEnd-clStart; //0 as well
```

It works fine when I insert for example Sleep() function inside but when using sin from math.h I always get 0 time. Why is that? I know it's probably optimized but 0? I want to compare that with other sin implementations but I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Try with `int o=0; o<100000;o++`

Comment: @Thomas ...alright this was dumb :D thanks it seems it's working
btw sin really doesn't take even one tick? I thought that clock returns number of ticks not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time used to calculate 100 sin is very short, you should use

```
auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
clStart = clock();

for (int o=0; o<100000;o++)
{
    sin(o);
   // Sleep(1);
}

auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
clEnd = clock();

auto difTime = end-start;
diff = chrono::duration <double,milli> (difTime).count();
diffTicks = clEnd-clStart;
```

instead.

Furthermore, your code measure milliseconds. I recommend you to use `chrono::duration <double, nano> (diff).count()` which use nanosecond for more precision.

---

From the doc:

> The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep. If Rep is floating point, then the duration can represent fractions of ticks. Period is included as part of the duration's type, and is only used when converting between different durations.

Which means that this is **not** CPU ticks you're measuring

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use the internal tick count. I usually used two classes to help me with that:

```
 class PACKAGE Profiler
 {
    public:
    Profiler()
    {
        totalTime=0;
        PCFreq = 0.0;
        numberOf =0.0;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
        PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        CounterStart = li.QuadPart;

    }
    __int64 CounterStart;
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    double totalTime;
    double PCFreq;
    long numberOf;

 };

 class PACKAGE Profiterol
 {
    private:
        Profiler* m_myprofiler;
    public:
    Profiterol(Profiler* a_prof)
    {
        m_myprofiler = a_prof;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_myprofiler->li);
        m_myprofiler->CounterStart = m_myprofiler->li.QuadPart;
        m_myprofiler->numberOf++;
    }
    ~Profiterol()
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_myprofiler->li);
        m_myprofiler->totalTime += double(m_myprofiler->li.QuadPart-m_myprofiler->CounterStart)/m_myprofiler->PCFreq;
    }

 };
```

And then, in your code you has to do this:

```
Profiler partial2;

{
  Profiterol tmp(&partial2);
        for (int o=0; o<100;o++)
        {
            sin(o);
           // Sleep(1);
        }
}
String strMeasureTime = String(partial2.totalTime) + "(" + String(partial2.numberOf)
```

In the strMeasureTime you will have the time.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one maybe too